# Engraving a text string in Blender Internal Render

Tags: modeling, mesh, text-object

I am trying to engrave a plaque (metal, stone) with some text.  The person who redirected me here had [this example](http://blenderyodamon.blogspot.com/2012/05/gold-bars.html) (with author's permission)

My current workflow is slow.  I prepare a picture of the text (in Gimp), use it as a bump map node in the "final" material (to influence the metal or stone texture).

I'm looking for a shortcut: can I use a Blender text (possibly on a separate layer, not rendered as such) to achieve the same?

I can create the engraving - the key is being able to change the text over, without altering the geometry using a boolean operation, or without re-creating the maps (bump or displacement).

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2612/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9005/599

Comment: What's wrong with using a boolean operator? Than you can just change the text and it will update the geometry. You could put the text in a separate layer and exclude it from the render.

Comment: @cegaton your answer seems good, the only thing to to is not applying the boolean and make the text not renderable with it's properties or changing layer.

Comment: @Bithur I edited the answer with your notes, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Create your lingot first. Add a text object and give it some thickness extruding it in the properties geometry tab.

[image]
[image]

Place the text where you need it and convert it to a mesh: <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> and select Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text

[image]

Select the Lingot,  add a Boolean Modifier and select the Text as object and use difference as operation.
[image]

You can now move the text to another layer that is not part of your rendered layers.

[image]

If you have different text objects you can change them by selecting them in boolean modifier.

Comment: It would be really cool if text objects could be used without text-to-mesh conversion...

Comment: I agree, but the boolean modifier does not allow for it...

Comment: yep, tried with modifiers on text (decimate, remesh) but the text object just can't be selected in boolean :(

Comment: @Bithur text objects are curves

Comment: yep, and modifiers won't change their original nature :(