# Can a curve object modifier created geometry be used as boolean factor

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

This question is related to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13924/11431).

Let me use an exemple to illustrate what I mean.

We've created a text object (made of curves). It can't be used in a boolean modifier as it won't appear in the list of usable objects in the modifier because it's a curve object.
[image]
But if we add a remesh modifier on the text, geometry is created from the shape.
[image]
The object could be used as boolean if we convert it to mesh. The remesh can't be applied on curve object.

**My question is** : Can we dynamicaly use the remesh modifier created geometry as real geometry or make the boolean modifier consider the text modified object as a real mesh?

The idea behind this is to be able to change the text (or any curve 3D shape) without having to make it a real mesh.

(don't hesitate to edit my poor english to make it understandable :) )

Comment: so lets get this straight, you're not wanting to use {Alt}+{C} > convert to mesh?

Comment: I don't! I want to be able to change the text AND use it as boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have guessed blender doesn't let you use a curve object for boolean operations. While the remesh modifier technically turns the result into a mesh, it is still a curve based object.

I think your best option is to duplicate the text <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to convert the duplicate to a mesh and use it for the boolean. As you leave the original text object you can delete the mesh text, alter the text and repeat.

Comment: This is Cegaton's answer on the linked question, but I want some magic trick!!! :)

Comment: You could make an addon/script to do all steps in one go.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to make a script to use the curve object as a fake mesh using the modifier created geometry?

Comment: An addon wouldn't make blender accept the curve object for the boolean, it could convert the text and hide the original, then set the the modifier, just simplifying the process to one command.