# Trying to join curve and plane together, but boolean won't work

Tags: modifiers

Been trying to get this vector showing in the screen shot to be welded together with the plane and I'm not able to join them using difference in the boolean modifier (assuming that's the correct way?).  The idea is to make the film strip look like glass and I added the plane to make up for the hollow parts (which would also be glass)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a curve object modifier created geometry be used as boolean factor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27114/can-a-curve-object-modifier-created-geometry-be-used-as-boolean-factor)

Comment: Curves (and text) do not work with booleans. you need to convert to mesh (Alt+C)

Comment: Got it thanks.  However, after converting to mesh it still didn't join the plane and vector when I did the boolean...why is that?

Comment: it looks like the file you uploaded is not the same as the file you are showing in this screenshot. it's difficult to tell you how to fix this without knowing the geometry in question.

Comment: Most of the time the Boolean Modifier is not the answer. Here too.