# Some modifiers missing in "add modifiers" tab

Tags: modifiers

When I go to the **Properties** tab, click on **Object Modifiers**, and then **Add Modifier**, I notice that a lot of the modifiers are missing.  For example, "Mask" modifier does not appear, "Boolean" also doesn't appear, and neither do several others (which would take a while to label). I'm using blender 2.76b, but I was also missing them in 2.74 (which I was using before 2.76b).

any ideas on what it could be?

[image: Image of the modifier tab]

Comment: What sort of object do you have selected?

Comment: @user20979 Please post the printscreen showing your issue [Window-->Save Screenshot (Ctrl+F3)].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all modifiers are available for all kinds of objects.
The main difference is between Mesh objects and Curve objects

For Mesh Objects you can use:

[image]

If you are dealing with **curves** (and text is considered a curve object) none of the modifiers you mention will be available, only these:

[image]

Comment: Booleans don't work with curves or text

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27114/can-a-curve-object-modifier-created-geometry-be-used-as-boolean-factor

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the kind of issue you've got, but in some cases you have to press the down arrow to scroll through modifiers.
[image]

Comment: you've saved my life