# Indented letters? (embossed)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm using v2.76, and I want to create a "stamp" effect with letters. I watched a video on how to do this, and the guy said to use the boolean modifier. I followed the steps exactly to the point where you select the modifier, and it does not show up. I was using cycles render, as was the guy in the video.

Examples:

https://365webresources.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Leather-Stamping-Logo-MockUp-2.jpg

http://gadgetsin.com/uploads/2011/05/bullet_shell_cufflinks_1.jpg

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't show up"?  What doesn't show up, the modifier or the letters?

Comment: The modifier. I saw it in the list of modifiers when nothing is selected, however.

Comment: Make sure the object which should be indented (i.e. not the text) is the *active* object (bright yellow outline).

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13930/1853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text object must be converted to mesh (<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> -> "mesh from ..."), or you cannot use boolean on it. If you don't convert it, you cannot neither use the boolean on the other mesh which has to be embossed, because you cannot select the text as target object. When you convert the text to mesh, both can be done.

My suggestion, also, is to operate as logic suggests: select the "other mesh", apply the boolean modifier, as "difference", and select the (converted to mesh) text as target "object".